# Tracking the network traffic from an unknown MAC address on WIFI

Tags: mac-address

I have a MAC address on my WiFi network that I do not recognize.

The unknown device asks for, and receives, an IP from my dhcp server.

I tried the following to find out the origin:

- All my devices (especially iOS) have been set not to use a private MAC.
- I checked the dhcp logs to see if a name was specified with the DHCP REQ: none.
- I tried ssh into it: no connection.
- I tried pinging the IP: nothing comes back.
- I periodically run `netstat-nat` and see if the IP is listed, no traffic.
- Looking up the MAC does not give a known vendor.
- I have two unmanaged switches on my LAN, one of which has a MAC known to me. It can't be the other switch, because unmanaged switches do not request an IP via HDCP.

What else can I do to find out about the suspect MAC?

I know that it comes in via WIFI (Airport Extreme) that is in bridge mode, and then connects to my router with DHCP.

I find the MAC via:
`/usr/sbin/brctl showmacs br0` and the aging timer runs up to 90s or so, and then goes to 0. So I assume it is active on the network every 90 seconds?

The fact that it sees my router behind the bridging wifi, means it must have my WiFi password.

Comment: If you don't know what it is, why are you not changing the PSK? Indeed, why would you be running PSK?

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit network appliance/switch dependent, but I would do port mirroring and dump all his traffic and analyze it

Comment: Port mirroring on unmanaged switches?

Answer (score 0):

I watched its network traffic, and saw it attempting to either lookup or connect to guzzoni.apple.com which meant siri.

It turns out it was an Apple Watch with private mac setting.